# Flutter - [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. In StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, get, flutter-layout, flutter-getx, stream-builder

So I try to use getx to change some value inside the singleStudentDataMobile open from a streambuilder and it throw this error and I dont know hot to fix this

It is get datafrom firebase and show data and this page will show all details when tap on the listview

`

```
  throw """
  [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
  You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
  If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
  or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
  (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
  If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
  """;
```

this is the code

My Code:-

```
class singleStudentDataMobile extends StatefulWidget {
  const singleStudentDataMobile({Key? key, required rdata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<singleStudentDataMobile> createState() =>
      _singleStudentDataMobileState();
}

final StudentDetailsMobi studentdetails = Get.put(StudentDetailsMobi());

Color Activeiconcolor = blue500;

class _singleStudentDataMobileState extends State<singleStudentDataMobile> {
  int getselecticon = studentdetails.selectfield.value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgcolor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          shadowColor: blue500,
          backgroundColor: darkblue2,
          title: Text("Student Details"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The error it's self-explanatory

Comment: The reason behind the error is that you wrap a non-reactive or a state that doesn't change so there is no need to wrap such a block with Obx. Try to remove the Obx your error will be gone. In your case under Obx there is no such Rx variable so you don't need Obx in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. Looking at the code, I see that there are no variables from the Getx Controller under the Obx.

From the Controller, if you set **var test = 10.obs** or another variable and show this value under OBX, the problem will disappear.